# C Skips Function Over

Tags: c

I have an issue with a test app im modifying to get better acquainted with the Pebble App SDK and C. Im trying to get my code to run the function `inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context)` but for whatever reason, C skips over the code and proceeds to run other functions. All other functions prewritten in the example run without trouble.

Why does C decide to skip over this function and how do I prevent it from skipping over this code.

**weather_app_data.c**

```
    ...other functions listed
void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {
  // Store incoming information
    strcpy(city, "test");
     static char temperature_buffer[8];
  static char conditions_buffer[32];
  static char weather_layer_buffer[32];
  // Read first item
  Tuple *t = dict_read_first(iterator);

  // For all items
  while(t != NULL) {
    // Which key was received?
    switch(t->key) {
    case KEY_0:
      snprintf(temperature_buffer, sizeof(temperature_buffer), "%dC", (int)t->value->int32);
      break;
    case KEY_1:
      snprintf(conditions_buffer, sizeof(conditions_buffer), "%s", t->value->cstring);
      break;
    default:
      APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Key %d not recognized!", (int)t->key);
      break;
    }

    // Look for next item
    t = dict_read_next(iterator);
  }


}

}


static WeatherAppDataPoint s_data_points[] = {
    {
        .city = city, //This value is left blank by C even though defined in function that isn't running
        .description = "Light Rain.",
        .icon = WEATHER_APP_ICON_LIGHT_RAIN,
        .current = 68,
        .high = 70,
        .low = 60,
    },
    ...other items
};
```

**weather_app_data.h**

```
... other functions all listed
void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context);
 void inbox_dropped_callback(AppMessageResult reason, void *context);
 void outbox_failed_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, AppMessageResult reason, void *context);
```

Comment: So you are ruling out that `Tuple *t = dict_read_first(iterator);` never returns `NULL`? If you don't have a debugger, add a line `if (t) printf("t is not NULL\n");` below that one to test.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `inbox_received_callback()`?   Writing a function isn't enough.   Some other function needs to call it.

Comment: What proof do you have that "*C skips over the code*"?

Comment: A callback is usually passed to another function, and that other function uses it to communicate back to you with status information (you call it, and it's *calling you back* - thus the name *callback*). Where is the code where you pass in the address of `inbox_received_callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't provide enough code to give a certain answer, but based on what you do show I think @Peter has hit the nail on the head.

You don't show any code calling `inbox_received_callback`. Depending on your compiler optimization flags you could see at least 2 different things:

1. Your function doesn't show up in the disassembly because the compiler optimized out the function since no one called it (usually happens with -O2 and greater).
2. You will see your function in the disassembly, but it still does nothing because no one called it (seen with -O0).

Comment: @Peter did nail it, it was a primitive mistake of me to make while editing more complex C code. After carefully looking through, I forgot to include the function in my main() function, so nothing ran.